# npm i Microsoft SDK 10 error

Tags: windows, git, sdk

I'm trying use this

```
C:\Users\User npm i
```

I get such error log that windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 is not found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWevn.png)

I checked the Visual Studio and there it is installed

Comment: That doesn’t look like a valid command...

Comment: @evolutionxbox npm install

Comment: Is `C:\Users\User` where you are supposed to run this command?

Comment: @evolutionxbox
C:\Users\User> cd C:\Users\User\hello_world_dapp

C:\Users\User\hello_world_dapp> npm install

Comment: Can you verify that the folder has a `package.json` file in it?